# how could I find the roles and permissions in sql server having administrative privileges

Tags: sql, sql-server, admin, roles, sql-function

I want find the roles and permissions in sql server having administrative privileges

Comment: What do you define as an "administrator"?

Comment: A role which can have access to perform all kinds of operation for example: sysadmin

Comment: Have a look at the `sys.server_role_members` object.

Comment: so you mean that users in `sys.server_role_members` will always be mapped to admin roles ?

Comment: No `USER`s will appear in `sys.server_role_members`, as a `USER` is a database object. That object tells you what server principles belong to server roles; then you can simply join back to the server principles object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Old style using IS_SRVROLEMEMBER :

   ```sql
   SELECT   name,type_desc,is_disabled
   FROM     sys.server_principals 
   WHERE    IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('sysadmin',name) = 1
   ORDER BY name
   ```
2. Using sys.server_role_members

   ```sql
   SELECT 'Name' = sp.NAME
   ,   sp.is_disabled AS [Is_disabled]
   FROM sys.server_role_members rm
   JOIN    sys.server_principals sp ON rm.member_principal_id = sp.principal_id
   WHERE rm.role_principal_id = SUSER_ID('Sysadmin')
   ```

Reference:
[SQL SERVER – Query to Get the List of Logins Having System Admin (sysadmin) Permission](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/01/11/sql-server-query-get-list-logins-system-admin-sysadmin-permission/)

Comment: It's really past time you stop using that 31 year old  implicit JOIN syntax: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). It was superseded some 28 years ago now.

Comment: All credits to Pinal (reference link). But fully agree with you, nobody likes that old Oracle style